# Retrieving Database entries and putting them into a php array

Tags: javascript, php, sql, arrays, postgresql

My database contains records with file path's to pictures in them.
I would like to retrieve these records and put them into a php array so that I can display the pictures on my webpage. The pictures will be displayed in the center of the page with left and right buttons for navigation.

The goal I'm hoping to achieve is that when the left button is pressed, it will display the previous record,and when the right button is pressed, it will show the next record

I'm told that working with javascript and arrays would be the best route to follow. Therefore if anyone could show me how to do so, it would be much appreciated

Entries would be ordered by the picture_id and the field containing the path is labeled file_location

The database query.The table `presentation` is given a unique `code` and `id` and the table `slide` is what contains the `file_location` and also has a unique `id` as well as the `id` of the presentation it belongs to.

```
$sql_pres_slide= new CGenRs("SELECT * FROM presentation", $cao);
        $sql_pres_slide->first();
        $sql_pres_select= new CGenRs("SELECT * FROM slide where presentation_id='".$sql_pres_slide->valueof('pres_id')."'", $cao);
        $sql_pres_select->first();
```

The html

```
<table border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><span onclick="<?php echo "PREVIOUS DATABASE RECORD" ?>" style="color: #999; font-size: 25px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" ></span></td>
        <td> <div class="backgrund_img" >

        <img src="../administration/file_manager/files/samsungS4-portrait-white.png" class="background_img" style="height:786px; width:406px; " />
        <div id="inside_img"><img src="<?php echo $sql_pres_select->valueof('file_location')  ?>" style="width: 360px; height:640px;"/></div>

    </div>  
</td>
<td><span onclick="<?php echo "NEXT DATABASE RECORD" ?>" style="color: #999; font-size: 25px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" ></span></td>
    </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: Check out the many many (many!) jQuery image sliders that are available with a quick Google.

Comment: You can use `javaScript` array to store the images path and play around array `indexes` as per the user navigation!

Comment: @RayonDabre I'll have a look at it, and report back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to have understood your problem but it seems to me that there is a little bit of confusion...
You want to implement a carousel (and there are so many in the web, ready to use) but overall, you are talking about the fetching of your images using javascript, when user presses left or right button.

In my opinion this is possible using two different approaches:
1. load all of your images into a javascript array
2. load the first image in a javascript var and use ajax calls to go back or forward.

let's see a couple of examples

First approach:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
var images=new Array(<?php implode($images);?>);
$().ready(function(){
  $('prev').click(function(){
    //go to previous image
  })
  $('next').click(function(){
    //go to next image
  })
})
</script>
```

Second approach:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
var images=<?php $images[0];?>;
$().ready(function(){
  $('prev').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "yourPhpImageScroller.php",
      data: {direction:'prev'},
      success: function(data){
        //go to previous image
      }
     });
    });
  }):
  $('next').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "yourPhpImageScroller.php",
      data: {direction:'next'},
      success: function(data){
        //go to next image
      }
     });
    });
  })
})
</script>
```

I'm assuming that $images is an php array containing all of your images

Comment: Yes, this pretty much sums up what I want to do with it. I am busy with the first approach now and will report back when I have completed it. In terms of answering my question... I needed guidance and you provided it.So this answer will be marked helpful! :)